# Axis of oscillation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, string

[image]

what would be the effective length of the pendulum if the block start oscillating in the plane perpendicular to the screen?

according to me the block would oscillate about AB and with the green line as its effective length

[image]

however, I really don't have an explanation for this.

moreover, it turns out I am wrong:(
the oscillations are supposed to happen about the orange line(AC) with DE as its effective length with

[image]

so, my question is how do I find the axis of oscillations, is there any method /logic behind this?

[Note: Points A,B and C are all fixed to the blue lines and D is attached to the block]

Comment: How do you define the effective length of a pendulum? Do you mean the length of a point mass ($M$) pendulum on a very low mass string ($m/M \to 0$) in the same gravitational field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can obtain the effective length $~DG~$ of the oscillator either with pendulum  equation of motion or from the  geometry .

[image]
[image]
**Geometry**

$$\tan{\alpha}=\frac{y_G}{a}=\frac{h_2-h_1}{a+b}\\
\Rightarrow\\
y_G=\frac{h_2-h_1}{a+b}\,a\\
DG_1=y_G+h_1=-{\frac { \left( -h_{{2}}+h_{{1}} \right) a}{a+b}}+h_{{1}}$$

**Pendulum equation**

the position vector $\vec R_m~$ to the mass is:

$$\vec R_m=\boldsymbol S(\vec{\hat{d}}~,\varphi)\,
\begin{bmatrix}
  a \\
  -h_1 \\
  0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

where $~\boldsymbol S~$ is Rodrigues  rotation matrix  , $\vec d~$  the rotation axis and $\varphi$ the rotation angle about $\vec d$

$$\vec d=\begin{bmatrix}
  a+b \\
  h_2-h_1 \\
  0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

from here you obtain the equation of motion

$$\ddot{\varphi}+\frac{a+b}{a\,h_2+b\,h_1}\,g\,\sin(\varphi)=0\\
$$
and after linearized you get:

$$\ddot{\varphi}+\underbrace{\frac{a+b}{a\,h_2+b\,h_1}}_{=\frac{1}{DG_2}}\,g\,\varphi=0\\
$$

you can see that both results are equal  $DG_1=DG_2$

Answer (score 0):

Your third picture is also wrong. The effective length of small oscillation will be $DG$:

[image]

The geometric explanation of it is more complicated here than a physics one. Due to symmetry point $D$ will be constrained to a circle with a centre at $E$. Gravity in the plane of the circle is $g_1 = g\cos\alpha$. Thus, the period of small oscillations will be :
$$
T = 2\pi\sqrt{\frac{DE}{g\cos\alpha}}.
$$

However, $DE/\cos\alpha = DG$. In other words,
$$
T = 2\pi\sqrt{\frac{DG}{g}}.
$$
Thus, we conclude that the effective length of a pendulum will be  $DG$.

Comment: i really appreciate ur answer but how do identify the axis and the effective length???

Answer (score 0):

For small oscillations about equilibrium in a uniform gravitational field, the angular frequency of oscillation is
$$\omega = \sqrt{\frac{mg\ell}{\mathcal{I}}}$$
where $\ell$ is the distance from the pivot point to the center of mass of the pendulum, and $\mathcal{I}$ is the moment of inertia of the pendulum about the pivot point.

We can develop that from the torque/angular acceleration form of Newton's 2nd law:
$$\sum \tau = \mathcal{I}\alpha,$$

$\tau$ is a torque acting on the object about the pivot, $\alpha$ is the angular acceleration.
$$-mg\ell\sin\theta=\mathcal{I}\frac{\mathrm d \theta^2 }{\mathrm d t^2}$$
$\theta$ is the angle measured with respect to the equilibrium position and the negative sign results from the fact that the torque is acting to restore equilibrium. For small oscillations $\sin\theta \simeq \theta$ in radians. The solution, $\theta(t)$, is sinusoidal with angular frequency as given above.

For the simple pendulum, $$\mathcal{I}=m\ell^2$$, and the angular frequency is the familiar $$\omega=\sqrt{\frac{g}{\ell}}.$$

For your problem, you need to find the perpendicular distance from  the AB axis to center of mass position and the moment of inertia about that axis. You might need to take advantage of the parallel axis theorem to find $\mathcal{I}$.

I'll let you calculate the specifics because that's merely algebra and geometry.